# Java starting two threads?

Tags: java, runnable

i am new to java. I have two classes that looks like:

```
public class hsClient implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    while(true){
    }
  }
}

public class hsServer implements Runnable {

  public void run() {
    while(true){
    }
  }
}
```

If i try to start both classes as Thread it wont start the second thread. It looks like he stuck in the first one.

This is my main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        hsClient client = new hsClient();
        Thread tClient = new Thread(client);
        tClient.run();
        System.out.println("Start Client");
        hsServer server = new hsServer();
        Thread tServer = new Thread(server);
        tServer.run();
        System.out.println("Start Server");
}
```

If i run my code it only prints "Start Client" but not "Start Server" on the console

Comment: I don't know what IDE you use but if you use Netbeans or Eclipse you can use breakpoints to check where it goes wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `tClient.run()` with `tClient.start()` and `tServer.run()` with `tServer.start()`.

Calling the `run` method directly executes it in the current thread instead of in a new thread.

Comment: The same to the tServer :)

Answer (score 1):

To start a thread use the `start` method.

```
Thread tClient = new Thread(client);
tClient.start(); // start the thread
```

More info on threads can be found e.g. in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)