# Why is multi-threaded Java code behaving like single-threaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I would expect the following code to print out on the first line: initial value.

```
public class RunnableLambda {

    static String accessedByThreads = "initial value";

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Runnable r8 = () -> {
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("r8");
            accessedByThreads = "from runnable lambda";
        };
        r8.run();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("r");
                    accessedByThreads = "from runnable anonymous";
                }
            };
        r.run();
        System.out.println("Main");
        System.out.println(accessedByThreads);
    }
}
```

Because I would expect spawned threads to finish after the main. However, it prints out on the last line: from runnable anonymous.

Why?

Comment: Where do you think you're creating any other threads? You're just calling `run` on two `Runnable` objects...

Comment: You don't start a thread. You just call method run() from Runnable. Use start()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java starting two threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819356/java-starting-two-threads)

Comment: Thank you :) (I wonder what I have been drinking..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Runnable.run()` does not start a new Thread. It is a normal method call like on any other object. You need to call the [`Thread.start()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()) method to create a new Thread.

Instead of `r8.run();` you need to write

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (r8);
t1.start(); //this creates and runs the new thread in parallel
```

Same for `r.run();` use:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread (r);
t2.start();
```